# Apache .htaccess redirect from https to non https for single URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok, researched this one to death here and on Google. Trying to get an https URL to redirect to a non HTTPS URL.

I have tried all kinds of combos but, nothing is working for this URL:

https://www.urotoday.com/403-perspectives-from-the-editor-in-chief-june-2014

All I want to do is redirect to http://www.urotoday.com/403-perspectives-from-the-editor-in-chief-june-2014

This didn't; work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/403\-perspectives\-from\-the\-editor\-in\-chief\-june\-2014$
RewriteRule .* "http\:\/\/www\.urotoday\.com\/403\-perspectives\-from\-the\-editor\-in\-chief\-june\-2014" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule in your DOCUMENT_ROOT htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(403-perspectives-from-the-editor-in-chief-june-2014)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: Just reread and put the .htacess in the site root and it cause the whole site to 404 :(

Comment: The rule only targets one single file, so it cannot affect the whole site. You must have other rules in that htaccess clashing with this, or other problems with that htaccess. Can you see something like that in the file?  Did you create the file from scratch just now, or was it already there and you added these lines?

Comment: @anubhava Not a coding question so posted on ServerFault, but if in the coming days you find a chance to share your thoughts on [mod_rewrite mysteriously appends subfolder to rewritten url](http://serverfault.com/questions/607530/mod-rewrite-mysteriously-appends-subfolder-to-rewritten-url), I'd deeply appreciate it. :)

Comment: I will look into that question and will provide my comments there.

Comment: @zx81 I created it from scratch in the root. I'll look into the .htaccess in the site folder and see if one of the Joomla CMS rewrites might have caused that.

Comment: That must be frustrating, hope you find the source of the problem. :) Also: Just in case, you may want to look at the permissions on the htaccess file (should be fine) and at the encoding (make it unix-style just in case).